# Power Series Solution for Homogenous DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Problem.** I need to find a series solution for
$$y''+u^{2} y'-4uy = 0$$
using power series about $u_0 = 1$ where $y$ is in terms of $u$. Clearly this is an ordinary point. I obtained the recurrence formula
$$c_{n+3} = - \frac{(n-4)c_{n}}{(n+3)(n+2)}$$
I know that $c_2 = c_5 = c_8 = \ldots = c_{3k+2} = 0$. For $c_1 = c_4 = c_7 = \ldots = c_{3k+1}$, I noticed that $c_7 = 0$, and so the coefficients after it are also 0. At this point, however, I'm stuck. I don't see any pattern for $c_0 = c_3 = c_ 6 = \ldots = c_{3k}$. Any insights? Thanks!

Comment: found solution [here](https://12000.org/tmp/solved_problems/dec_26_2022.pdf)

Comment: As your series expansion has been made around $u_0 = 1$, i.e. $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{u^{(n)}(u_0)}{n!}(u-u_0)^n$, the first coefficient can be determined thanks to an initial/boundary condition, here $c_0 = u(u_0) = u(1)$. Then your recurrence relation gives all the coefficients of the type $c_{3k}$, probably without any cutoff, otherwise your solution would be a mere polynomial, since $c_2 = c_7 = 0$ already.

Comment: I got
$$y=y(0)-\frac{4y(0)}{2\cdot 3}x^3-\frac{4y(0)}{2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 6} x^6+4y(0)\sum_{n=3}^\infty{(-1)^{n+1}\frac{2\cdot 5\cdot 8\cdot 11\cdot 14\cdots(3n-7)x^{3n}}{2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 6\cdot 8\cdot 9\cdot 11\cdot 12\cdots (3n)}}+y'(0)x+\frac{y'(0)}{4}x^4.$$